# In an ID, find the % chance of at least two people with the same last digit?

Tags: probability

Just wanting someone to comment as to whether I'm doing this the right way or not as my answer seems wrong.

> Context:
>
> - Assume each person is equally likely to have any one of the 000 ... 999 as the last three digits of their ID number.
> - The ID is 7 characters long.
>
> Question:
>
> Find the % chance of at least two people with the same last digit in a group of five?

What I've attempted to do:

|S| = (10^7)^5 -- because there are 7 combinations of (0-9) and 5 people.

|E^c| = 10! / (10-5)! -- to consider that no one has the same last digit.

Putting it all together and subtracting the complement, I get P(at least two) = 1.

Is this correct? If not, what am I doing wrong?
Any tips would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why is it not $|S|=10^5$?

Comment: P(at least two) = 1? That should make you rethink ...

Comment: @Henry Yeah, that's what confused me. I thought I had to consider all the different combinations of ID digits as well -- but I do have a tendency to over-complicate things. 10^5 produces a more realistic answer haha. Thank you!

Comment: Quick question: say I had to calculate "at least two that have the same last THREE digits of their ID"; how would I adjust the event space for that?

Comment: Replace 10 by 1000 in your calculations